# August Month is not print properly in python

Tags: python, monthcalendar

```
List = ['Before : January 28, 1996 6:00:00 PM CST', 'After : December 1, 2028 6:59:59 PM CDT']
enddate_NO_pr = List[1].lstrip('After : ').replace(',','')
print enddate_NO_pr
December 1 2028 6:59:59 PM CDT
>>>
>>>
List = ['Before : January 28, 1996 6:00:00 PM CST', 'After : August 1, 2028 6:59:59 PM CDT']
enddate_NO_pr = List[1].lstrip('After : ').replace(',','')
print enddate_NO_pr
ugust 1 2028 6:59:59 PM CDT
```

> I have start and end date in my list. When i tried to fetch particular
>   items from my list.
>
> "August" Month alone is not display properly. Any suggestion,please.

Comment: it's because `August` start with `A` like `After` you shouldn't use `lstrip` :  http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/lstrip.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use [`lstrip()`](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/lstrip.html) in this case. It will not remove the prefix, but instead remove all leading characters that appear in the string you pass in.

Since `After :` contains a capital `A`, it will be stripped from `August` as well.

You could do something like this instead:

```
 enddate_NO_pr = List[1][len('After : '):].replace(',','')
```